# How to read node ids from an input box?

Tags: netlogo

I am pretty sure there are some basic glaring flaws here but assistance would be great. What I am trying to do is to use an input box so that a user can specify connections between specific nodes. The data that is being inputted is in the form of a string (reporter) and I am having problems getting the programme to recognise the input. The code is as follows;

```
ask circle 1 [ create-links-with  n-of 3 read-from-string connect-with ]
```

Comment: circle 1 is an attempt to specify a certain node upon which the code will act, is this correct?

Comment: We need more info.  I assume that `connect-with` is the variable that's attached to the input box.  What are you typing into it?  Are you getting an error message, or are you simply getting no new links?  (`circle` is a turtle breed right?)

Comment: Yes, `circle 1` refers to a `circle` if `circle` is a breed.  But see my comment at the end of my answer.

Comment: Oh, and one more general tip.  It's consider very bad form on StackExchange to provide such a non-specific title to your question.  It's also bad form to provide so little info.  (Your question probably would have been downvoted by now if it had been asked about a more popular programming tool.)

Comment: I've fixed the question text.

Answer (score 1):

There's not enough information, but I'm going to guess.  I'll assume that `circle` is a turtle-breed.

`create-links-with` wants an agentset, and `n-of` therefore needs an agentset as its second argument here.  I don't think you can create an agentset with `read-from-string`, since the documentation says that `read-from-string` will only produce 'a number, list, string, or boolean value, or the special value "nobody".'

However, you could do something like this:

```
create-links-with n-of 3 circles with [color = read-from-string connect-property]
```

I'm using `connect-property` instead of `connect-with`; it's the variable that would be attached to the input box, and you can replace color with some other `circles-own` variable that you've defined.

If you have a fixed set of properties with which to identify the `circle`s, it might be better to use a Chooser object, or even a slider, rather than an Input box.

(Outside of testing and experimentation, I think it's probably not the best strategy to identify turtles by their numbers.  It's better to give them variables, and use the values of the variables to identify them, e.g. by using `with`.)